# Two of the same resistors have different resistance?

Tags: resistors, multimeter, ohms-law

I am doing some work on the electronics of a guitar and in doing so was testing some old circuitry.

I noticed that there are two resistors each stamped with ‘223’. When checking the resistance of these two components I received the following:

[image: resistance 0.735m]
[image: resistance 251.2k]

I know one is K and one is M. There is still a variance of nearly 500k between the two. Why?

Is one of the resistors bad?

**edit**
On closer inspection these may be capacitors

Comment: Have to be careful making measurements like that in-situ, as other parts that are connected to the part you're trying to measure could influence the measurement.

Comment: Those are ceramic capacitors, 223 would be 22 nF. The resistance measurements come from everything else in that circuit.

Comment: There’s nothing else attached to the end of the circuit

Comment: And yes I posted that they are capacitors

Comment: I am definitely not an electrical engineer

Comment: I see a solder sucker on that blanket, if that guitars older than the 2000s it most likely has lead solder. at which point you're going to be getting lead dust everywhere if you're using that solder sucker.

Comment: @Barry, what was the purpose of your measurements? What did you hope to learn or solve?

Comment: Capacitors have capacitance. You are measuring resistance, capacitors don't have resistance.

Comment: Like I said not an ee. Someone I asked said they were resistors.

Comment: I am a software engineer by trade. If I give you two algorithms for linked list sorting, could you tell me which one was a hash map vs a traditional array? That’s basically the hurdle I have here.

Comment: @madhatter it’s 2006. I assumed it was not lead based because of the difficulty in melting the stuff. Lead based typically melts easier in experience.

Comment: The picture is not clear enough for me, can you post a better close-up of the component please? Looks like a diode for me.

Comment: Photo isn't quite clear enough to be sure, but it looks like the left-hand (as we look) pots are tone, right-hand ones are volume. The capacitors are in series with the tone pots to apply a variable amount of treble cut. I think the ground end of the pot is grounded to the case, then perhaps the case is grounded via the mounting plate, assuming it is metal. (If it's not metal, there appears to be no other grounding for the pot so this may be the fault OP is searching for). Hard to tell from the photo.